# Evaluating form input radio button with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I am setting a h2 element to display the score of questions answered via radio buttons in a form. The congratulations message pops up when the answer is correct but the h1 text changes for a millisecond and then goes back to displaying zero.

```
var h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
var correctAnswers = 0;
h2.textContent = correctAnswers;

function getAnswer(){
  var radio = document.querySelector("form");
  if (radio[0].checked === true) {
    correctAnswers++;
    alert("Congrats! That answer is correct!");

  }
  h2.textContent = correctAnswers;
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", getAnswer);
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<body>
<h1></h1>
<form>

    <p>John Resig invented which javascript library?</p>
<input type="radio" name="library" value="jQuery">jQuery
<input type="radio" name="library" value="Lodash">Lodash
<input type="radio" name="library" value="Underscore">Underscore 
<input id="btn" type="submit"> </form>

<script src="quiz.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Can you also add the html?

Comment: linter and the console don't show any errors with the js

Answer (score 1):

```
Your page is reloading on submit to avoid that you can use as below
 form onsubmit="return false;"
<body>
<h2></h2>
<form onsubmit="return false;">

    <p>John Resig invented which javascript library?</p>
<input type="radio" name="library" value="jQuery">jQuery
<input type="radio" name="library" value="Lodash">Lodash
<input type="radio" name="library" value="Underscore">Underscore 
<input id="btn" type="submit"> </form>

<script>
var h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
var correctAnswers = 0;
h2.textContent = correctAnswers;

function getAnswer(){
  var radio = document.querySelector("form");
  if (radio[0].checked === true) {
    correctAnswers++;
    alert("Congrats! That answer is correct!");

  }
  h2.textContent = correctAnswers;
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", getAnswer);
</script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Nihar. That solved it! Noticed how much is wrong with my code other than that though. After three months with vanilla JS I am finally relenting and using jQuery for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

When I load your code and check my browser console, I see this message:

> TypeError: h2 is null
>
> h2.textContent = correctAnswers;

That is because this line is specifying an 'h2':

```
var h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
```

You can change `<h1></h1>` to `<h2></h2>` in your html, or add `<h2></h2>`.

If I for example add `<h2></h2>`, you indeed see the changing 1 back to zero.
That is because the form does a GET request when you click the button and the page reloads.

If you don't want the page to reload after to click the button, you can for example add this to the form tag:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Snippet:

```js
var h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
var correctAnswers = 0;
h2.textContent = correctAnswers;

function getAnswer(){
  var radio = document.querySelector("form");
  if (radio[0].checked === true) {
    correctAnswers++;
    alert("Congrats! That answer is correct!");

  }
  h2.textContent = correctAnswers;
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", getAnswer);
```

```html
<h2></h2>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <p>John Resig invented which javascript library?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="library" value="jQuery">jQuery
    <input type="radio" name="library" value="Lodash">Lodash
    <input type="radio" name="library" value="Underscore">Underscore
    <input id="btn" type="submit"> </form>
```